# Understanding the types of functions

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming, semantics

I am trying to understand the types of functions and being able to explain them.

Two functions:

```
insert :: t -> Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])
insert a True (b,c) = (a:b,c)
insert a False (b,c) = (b,a:c)

partition :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> ([t],[t])
partition p [] = ([],[])
partition p (x : xs) = insert x (p x) (partition p xs)
```

From my limited knowledge I think that insert function:

- `insert` is of type t, it takes two arguments one of bool and one of a tuple of two lists of type t and returns a tuple of two lists of type t.
- `partition` is a tuple of type t which returns a bool, and it takes a list of type t as it's argument and returns a tuple of two lists of type t.

Is that the right way of thinking about it or am I getting it wrong? I have been following some tutorials and this is what I've u   nderstood so far.

Comment: Looks like you have a too basic understanding of currying, which is an important concept in Haskell. Have a look at [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)

Comment: `insert` is not of type `t`, its *first argument* is of type `t`. `insert a` takes two more argument as you described. --- `partition` is not a tuple, it is a function. its first argument `p` is not a tuple, it is a function.

Answer (score 10):

> `insert` is of type `t`, it takes two arguments one of `Bool` and one of a tuple of two lists of type `t` and returns a tuple of two lists of type `t`.

**No**. First of all it is important to notice that in Haskell each function takes *exactly* one parameter. Indeed

```
insert :: t -> Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])
```

is a short and compact form of:

```
insert :: t -> (Bool -> (([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])))
```

in fact the above is still not very verbose, a canonical form would be:

```
insert :: ((->) t) (((->) Bool) (((->) ((,) ([] t)) ([] t))  ((,) ([] t)) ([] t)))
```

but the above is of course not very readable, let us thus stick to the second form.

Each function in Haskell takes exactly one parameter. What here happens is that the *result* of applying a parameter to a certain function, generates a new function.

So if we would generate an expression `insert x`, we have constructed a function of the type `Bool -> (([t], [t]) -> ([t], [t]))`.

*Informally*, one indeed sometimes says that a "*function takes n parameters*". But it is important to keep that in mind.

Secondly you forgot about the `t`. We can informally say that `insert` takes *three* parameters, a value of type `t`, a boolean (type `Bool`), and a 2-tuple with two lists of `t`s. It will return a 2-tuple of two lists of `t`s. Depending on whether the `Bool` is `True` or `False` it prepends one of the two lists with the given value.

For example:

```
Prelude> insert 5 False ([], [])
([],[5])
Prelude> insert 5 False ([1,4], [2,5])
([1,4],[5,2,5])
Prelude> insert 5 True ([1,4], [2,5])
([5,1,4],[2,5])
Prelude> insert 3 True ([1,4], [2,5])
([3,1,4],[2,5])
Prelude> insert 3 False ([1,4], [2,5])
([1,4],[3,2,5])
```

> `partition` is a tuple of type `t` which returns a `bool`, and it takes a list of type `t` as it's argument and returns a tuple of two lists of type `t`.

No, the parameter here has type `(t -> Bool)` that is a *function*. Indeed in Haskell you can pass functions as parameters.

Informally we can say that `partition` takes a "*predicate*" (a function that maps values to `Bool`s) and a list of `t`s, and it returns a 2-tuple with two lists of `t`s. Depending on whether the predicate holds for the values in the list, these are sorted in the first or the second list in the 2-tuple.

For example:

```
Prelude> partition (>3) [1,4,2,5]
([4,5],[1,2])
Prelude> partition (>3) [1,3,0,2]
([],[1,3,0,2])
Prelude> partition (>3) [1,7,8,0]
([7,8],[1,0])
Prelude> partition (>3) [1,7,8,9]
([7,8,9],[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

No, the types are exactly as shown:

`insert` has type `t -> Bool -> ([t], [t]) -> ([t], [t])`, which means it is a function that takes a value of type `t` as an argument and returns a function of type `Bool -> ([t], [t]) -> ([t], [t])`. Informally, you can think of `insert` as a function that takes 3 arguments: one of type `t`, one of type `Bool`, and one of type `([t], [t])`, and returns another value of type `([t], [t])`.

`partition` is a function that takes *another* function (of type `t -> Bool`) as its argument, and returns a function of type `[t] -> ([t],[t])`. Again informally, you can think of `partition` as taking two arguments (of type `t -> Bool` and type `[t]`) and returning a value of type `([t], [t])`.

`->` itself is a type-level operator; it takes two types as arguments and returns a function type. It is right-associative, which means `a -> (b -> c)` and `a -> b -> c` are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

No, `insert` is a *function*, so it can't be "of type `t`". If it were of type `t`, it would be a *value*:

```
a :: Int
a = 5
```

Here `a` is *of type* `Int`.

As you can see from the function implementation, `insert` takes *three* arguments:

```
insert a True (b,c) = ...
```

The arguments are `a`, `True` and `(b, c)`.

So, the type of `insert` is exactly `t -> Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`:

1. it's a function (because of `->`s)
2. ...of *one* argument of *some* type `t`
3. ...and returns *another function* of type `Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`

   1. ...which takes *one argument* of type `Bool` (and `Bool` only)
   2. ...and returns a function `([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`
   3. (this should be one level of indentation deeper) ...which takes one argument of type `([t],[t])` (a tuple of two lists, each of which holds values of *some* type `t`)
   4. ...and returns, finally, a *value* of type `([t],[t])`

Now, this looks like a mess: functions returning other functions that return functions... But this can be simplified. You can think of `insert` as a function of *three* arguments:

1. `insert` is this crazy function that returns other functions: type `t -> Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`
2. `insert 2` is of type `Bool -> ([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`
3. `insert 2 True` if of type `([t],[t]) -> ([t],[t])`
4. `insert 2 True ([1], [2])` is of type `([t],[t])`

*BOOM!* The last call actually returned a value, not a function! And due to this, one can treat `insert` as a function of three arguments. This thing is called currying, and it's named after the same man after whom Haskell is named - Haskell Curry.

Comment: Functions are values, too. The problem isn't that `t` isn't (or can't be) a function, it's that it doesn't *have* to be a function. For example, `id :: t -> t`, but both `id 'c'` and `id (+)` type-check because you can unify `t` with either `Char` or `Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: @chepner, yep, you worded it better. I was trying to draw a difference between values as some kind of data and functions as _behaviour_, while also attempting not to overcomplicate the answer with the fact that one can also pass functions to other functions.